# PhoneGap/Cordova for android file plugin error code 1

Tags: javascript, android, file, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap and i want to access a file located at www/res from an android device but it's throwing NOT_FOUND_ERR... I'm sure the file it's located there and here it's the code I wrote:

```
onDeviceReady: function(){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/res/myfile.txt", app.gotFile, app.fail);
},

gotFile: function(fileEntry){
    fileEntry.file(function(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            alert(this.result);
        }

        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
},

fail: function(e){
    console.log("Error reading");
    console.log(e.code);
}
```

The code it's super simple yet I can't see what's wrong with it!

Comment: could you please change path as `file:///android_asset/www/res/myfile.txt`

Comment: I tried that, doesn't work either

Answer (score 2):

The local URL cordova.file.applicationDirectory works for iOS but not Android.
You will have to iterate through the cordova.file.dataDirectory until you find the /res directory as a child of the GUID-named app directory.

Try the following:

```
var dirEntry = function (entry) {
    var dirReader = entry.createReader();
    dirReader.readEntries(
        function (entries) {
            $.each(entries, function (n, i) {
                if (i.isDirectory === true) {
                    if (i.nativeURL.indexOf('www/res') > -1) {
                        //found the target /res directory
                        var path = i.nativeURL + '/myfile.txt';
                        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, app.gotFile, app.fail);
                        return false; //no need to iterate more
                    } else {
                        // Recursive -- call back into this subdirectory
                        dirEntry(i);
                    }
                }
            });

        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("readEntries error: " + error.code);
        }
    );
};

var dirError = function (error) {
    console.log("getDirectory error: " + error.code);
};

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, dirEntry, dirError);
```

Comment: When console logging I found my nativeURL looked something like this:

file:///data/data/com.tkj.textread/files/12590FAA-5EDD-4B12-856D-F52A0A1599F2/res/

Answer (score 1):

I could try the code you have given. It works fine if you change the function name `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` to `resolveLocalFileSystemURI`, at least for me. You can see [PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem)

Comment: Ok, I did that and got an console log that says "resolveLocalFileSystemURI" is deprecated and should use "resolveLocalFileSystemURL"... And still even with the URI I get the not found error. How did you try the code? I am using phonegap's app on my android device to test it...

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use relative path. Of course it depends on where the code you stated in the question is located. I assume this code is inside default phonegap index.js file whose directory is 'www/js/index.js'. Relative path to txt file would be '../res/myfile.txt'.

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("../res/myfile.txt", app.gotFile, app.fail);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I don't think It supports relative paths.